# stereo sequence small disparity

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i need a stereo sequence (stereo pair images) to use it in my disparity learning algorithm but the disparity must be very small up to 3 pixels shift maximum, i don't know where to find it or how to create it,

any help? thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12678/stereo-sequence-small-disparity/) by [iisous](https://answers.ros.org/users/1664/iisous/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-01-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depending on your needs it might make sense to create a setup in (gazebo) simulation for easily generating stereo datasets. This way, you could also easily reconfigure the baseline and other parameters of both cameras. The PR2 head has two stereo cameras, so you could look into the corresponding URDF file for reference (see [here](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_description)). A 3 pixel max disparity seems really small to me, but you know your application better than me ;)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1